# User cannot upload to Media directory on Pythonanywhere

Tags: python, django, pythonanywhere

I'd like to submit a form where there is a filefield, in developpement mode I can submit it successfully but when it comes to pythonanywhere I'm redirected to my custom fail page which means the form didn't get through.

The form is saved when there are no attachments, it works on debug true & false on developpement (username.pythonanywhere.com) but not on product (www.domain.com)

Here is how I configured pythonanywhere files :

**settings.py :**

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
DEBUG = False

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

**urls.py** :

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**models.py**

```
class AskTicket(models.Model):
    document = models.FileField(upload_to='attachments')
    ...
```

And here is how I setup the static files manager :

[image]

Why users cannot download files ? Did I miss something ?

Comment: PythonAnywhere dev here -- are there any errors in your error log?  (There's a link to it just above the static files table.)

Answer (score 0):

How about following `DjangoGirls Tutorial`?

you can find it on https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/deploy/

so you have to do like this:

```
import os
import sys

path = '/home/<your-PythonAnywhere-username>/my-first-blog'  # use your own PythonAnywhere username here

if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mysite.settings'

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from django.contrib.staticfiles.handlers import StaticFilesHandler
application = StaticFilesHandler(get_wsgi_application())
```

Comment: didn't you forgot to collectstaticfiles?

Comment: would you delete 'upload_to' argument in FileField?

Comment: oh, so you can upload through admin, not with your custom form?

Comment: umm, would you remove /static/admin/ from  PA's static files settings?
if you did `collectstatic`, then it could be duplicated. (I know this approach is going-around, but let's check step-by-step.)